# Representing a hex string as separate numerical values?

Tags: java, android, hex, data-conversion

I am working on a BLE scanner application in which a BLE broadcaster is sending advertisement packets for the application to scan and display. I am currently using the getBytes() function in my android studio code to receive the data as a byte array, however when printed using this function, it gives 8 random symbols letters and numbers which change each time (Not correct).

```
byte[] packetData = Scanned.getBytes();
```

To allow it to print correctly i have added a for loop that converts the byte array into a hex string for readability.

```
//conversion to a hex stream from the byte array
            for (byte hex : packetData) {
                x.append(String.format("%02X", hex));
            }
```

I would like to take the hex string and store each it in an array as follows:

0x02012404FF as [02, 01, 24, 04, FF]

I have tried this code i found similar to my question but it did not display correctly.

```
byte [] data = new byte[PacketLength/2];

            for (int i =0;i<PacketLength;i+=2){
                data[i/2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(x.charAt(i), 16)<< 4)+Character.digit(x.charAt(i+1),16));
            }
```

EDIT:

CODE:

```
    private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            // gets data from the BLE scan for broadcasting packets
            ScanRecord Scanned = result.getScanRecord();
            String address = btAdapter.getAddress();

            //Gets advertised packets in a byte array
            byte[] packetData = Scanned.getBytes();
            //gtes length of packet data
            int PacketLength = packetData.length;




            StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
            String[] data = new String[PacketLength];
            //conversion to a hex stream from the byte array
            for (byte hex : packetData) {
                x.append(String.format("%02X", hex));
            }



            for (int i =0;i<PacketLength;i++){
                data[i] = String.format("%02X", packetData[i]);
            }




            //Filters the scan by nameed device, easily changable
            if (new String("SimpleBLEBroadcaster1").equals(result.getDevice().getName())) {
                peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " Rssi: " + result.getRssi() + " Packet length: " + PacketLength + "\n" +  " Packet Data: " +   "0x" + x + "\n"); //Prints data for the first broadcaster
                X =x;
                //Shared Preferences for Broadcaster 1
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
                //Allows the advertised data packets to be stored within the app for future use
                editor.putString("Data", String.valueOf(X));
                RSSI1 = result.getRssi();
                editor.putInt("Rssi", RSSI1 );

                //commits your edits
                editor.commit();
            }
            //filter for second device (required for my Chip design)
            if (new String("SimpleBLEBroadcaster2").equals(result.getDevice().getName())) {
                StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
                y=x; // Changes the Hex stream detected for the second device to a new variable for storage purposes
                peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " Rssi: " + result.getRssi() + " Packet length: " + PacketLength + "\n" +  " Packet Data: " +  "0x" + y + "\n");//Prints data for the second broadcaster
                Y=y;
                //Shared Preferences for Broadcaster 2
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit();
                //Allows the advertised data packets to be stored within the app for future use
                editor.putString("Data", String.valueOf(Y));
                RSSI2 = result.getRssi();
                editor.putInt("Rssi", RSSI2 );

                //commits your edits
                editor.commit();
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are supposed to do. Do you need to convert bytes to integers or hex values to integers? So should hex `AB` be returned as 171 or as [10,11]?

Comment: Indeed. Not enough info. If you have a byte stream then you do not have a hex stream. And if you are not told how many bytes would form a numerical value then you can do nothing. So ask then tell us.

Comment: Sorry for deleting the question, i made sure i knew what I needed exactly before continuing the question. Hopefully my edits provide more detail @Thomas

Comment: In that case, why don't you store the individual strings you get from `String.format("%02X", hex)`? Assuming you're feeding in the bytes that represent 0x02012404FF you should get the array `["02", "01", "24", "04", "FF"]`.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, I am a Java novice, how would i do this? Currently i am printing the variable x and it gives me my 62 bit data string, how would i be able to store it separately?

Comment: Just create a `List<String>` and `add(...)` the individual strings to it.

Comment: @user16320675 This does make sense, upon application and then in attempt to print it on my app I recieved " [Ljava.lang.String;@5786214"  Where the 7 bits at the end changed at each scan result. This isnt what i was expecting.  I will add the code to the question for reference

Comment: Thanks @user16320675 , unfortunately i cannot manually write the array elements. The data is 62 bits long and varies with different devices that are being scanned for (this is a BLKE scanner app im working on)

Comment: @user16320675 with reference to the link you sent where the array elements are defined within the code as opposed to a read in variable. I can print the data fine and display the Hex as a string in my app as well . just when i use ```data[i] = (String.format("%02X", packetData[i]));``` within a loop it doesn't store the values as it should

Comment: @user16320675 Thank you for that link. Apologies for my lack of explanation. I was missing the Arrays.toString and tried to just print the data array. Feel free to link that code as an answer and i can approve it